# Git - comparing to repository throw error

Tags: git, github

I am trying to have the `diff` between my local repo with `git repo` but I am getting error instead of getting difference.

here is the command i run : `git diff origin/color-palette/start.txt start.txt` basically i am trying to get the different between both `start.txt` file here.

the error i am getting is :

```
PS C:\Tutorials\try\color-palette> git diff origin/color-palette/start.txt start
.txt
fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/color-palette/start.txt': unknown revision or
path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
PS C:\Tutorials\try\color-palette>
```

What is wrong here? and how to exactly get diff between local and remote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for [`git diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) is:

```
git diff remotename/branchname:remote/path/afile.txt local/path/afile.txt
```

The second `local/path/afile.txt` is a shortcut for `HEAD:local/path/afile.txt`

In your case:

```
git diff origin:start.txt start.txt
```

No need for `color-palette` here, since it might be the root folder of your local repo.

Not that if you are comparing with a remote, it is generally a good idea to update the local image of that remote in your repo first:

```
git fetch
```

Then you can do a `git diff`, which works with what is in your local `.git/remotes/origin`: it won't make an actual query to the remote repo.

Comment: getting error as `fatal: Invalid object name 'origin/color-palette'.`

Comment: @user2024080 just to be sure, is `color-palette` a branch name. Can you do a `git fetch`, followed by `git branch -avv`, and tell me if that branch is listed there?

Comment: the file is not in branch

Comment: @user2024080 ok: where `color-palette` comes from? Is it a folder? I see it is the root folder of your repo. Fixing the answer now.

Comment: yes. under the master it there (https://github.com/3gwebtrain/color-palette/blob/master/start.txt)

Comment: @user2024080 OK, I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: I ran this command : ` git diff origin:start.txt start.txt` but getting no result. But visually i see the different between the files

Comment: @user2024080 Did you made a git fetch first? And can you include a screenshot illustrating the differences, but also between *what* you are comparing to show the differences. Are those difference end-of-line related? If yes, do a `git config core.autocrlf false`, clone again, and see if the differences persist.

Comment: Yes, you are right. after i do the `fetch` I got the result. thanks

Comment: @user2024080 OK, I have edited the answer to clarify the importance of a preliminary `git fetch`.